# AWS S3 Reading a file: Java 8 Stream giving java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to read a file from S3 bucket using the following logic.

```
public String readInputFile(String inputFileName) {
        String result = null;
        try (S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, inputFileName))) {     
            Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent())).lines();           
            LOG.info("Getting headers");
            LOG.info("S3 Object" + object.getObjectContent());
            LOG.info("Lines from the Input File"+stream.toString());
            if(object!=null){
            String[] headers = headers(object);
            LOG.info("Headers are: "+ headers);
             result = stream.skip(1) // skip headers
                    .map(line -> line.split(",")).map(data -> {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        LOG.info("Info in each line" + data);
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            map.put(headers[i], data[i]);
                        }
                        LOG.info("Map of the input"+map);
                        return map;
                    ***}).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\{\\}\\]]", "");***
             LOG.info("Result of converting to map"+ result);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FileProcessorAlerts.addAlert("IOException caught while reading " + inputFileName + " file " + e.getMessage());
            LOG.error("IOException caught while reading " + inputFileName + " file " + e);
        }
    return result;
    }
```

When I run this code it is giving me an error saying

**Java.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream**

near the highlighted with stars in the above code.Can someone please help me resolve this error.

Comment: You call `getObjectContent` twice - sure you’re allowed to do that? Also, why not use the `joining` collector rather than collecting to a `List` and then doing regex on the `toString`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I tried using joining and I got this error "The method collect(Collector<? super Map<String,String>,A,R>) in the type Stream<Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,String>)". I used the getObjectContent in the logger. Not sure if I can use it twice. In the logs I see the error pointing to the collect Method.

Comment: I would suggest you remove the log line and try again.